# Get Year from a Parameter with a date function

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters, datepart

I need to get the year **YYYY** from a parameter **(@PrmEnd2)** with a

```
default value  =
DateAdd("d" , -1 , DateAdd("m", -3, DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), 1)))
```

I have tried =`Year(Parameters!PrmEnd2.Value)` but keep getting **#ERR**

Please help. thank you

Comment: What is the value of `Parameters!PrmEnd2.Value`? Is this a `DateTime`?

Comment: Yes it is a datetime value

Comment: I did a quick test and all your code worked fine for me. If you use `=Year(CDate(Parameters!PrmEnd2.Value))` does it make any difference? Have you run the report in Visual Studio preview and looked at the errors it shows in the output?

Comment: still coming up with an error.

Comment: Try `Today()` not `Now()`. The `Now()` includes a time component also...

Comment: Also where are you trying to put this parameter? In a text box with particular number formatting? If so try to display just the parameter and format it as `yyyy`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use DatePart e.g.

```
=DatePart("yyyy",Paremeters!PrmEnd2.Value)
```

Or it could be that DateSerial exports data in Variant format.

Comment: Sorry Dan, came up saying yyyy not delcared

Comment: Hi Dan, the proble with the not declared was the spelling of paramater - however, it is still returning #ERROR. The parameter shows as a datetime when called.

Answer (score 0):

Change the datatype for **@PrmEnd2** to **Date/Time**. You should be getting the year value for `Year(Parameters!PrmEnd2.Value)`.

Or

Try Datatype for **@PrmEnd**2 as Text and expression as `Year(cdate(Parameters!PrmEnd2.Value))`.

Or

Use expression `Year(DateAdd("d" , -1 , DateAdd("m", -3, DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), 1))))`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the issue lies when you try to concatenate a string with a numeric... Try to convert the year to string.

in example:

**STR**( Year(Now()) )